# Создание целого числа с помощью int()

Tags: python-3.x, int

Почему при создании int с помощью float `int(21.0)` все выполняется, но при попытке создать int с помощью строкового литерала с десятичной дроббью `int('21.0')` выскакивает ошибка ValueError?

Comment: Потому что так реализовали. Чем более всеядной будет функция, тем выше вероятность ложной интерпретации входных данных. Строка `21.0` и float `21.0` это разны типы и поэтому не надо ждать что обрабатываться они будут одинаково. Это вопрос из разряда почему int `'ten'` в `10` не конвертирует?